# VTK.js VR not display/showing an hand controller in Room

Tags: javascript, webvr, vtk.js

I try to use VTK VR, but When I test it, I cant see controller in room, I can get action from controller like press or somthing, but without its seen for user in VR mode, how I can fix it?

[Online Demo From Here.](https://kitware.github.io/vtk-js/examples/VR.html)

```
    import 'vtk.js/Sources/favicon';

import vtkActor from 'vtk.js/Sources/Rendering/Core/Actor';
import vtkCalculator from 'vtk.js/Sources/Filters/General/Calculator';
import vtkConeSource from 'vtk.js/Sources/Filters/Sources/ConeSource';
import vtkFullScreenRenderWindow from 'vtk.js/Sources/Rendering/Misc/FullScreenRenderWindow';
import vtkMapper from 'vtk.js/Sources/Rendering/Core/Mapper';
import { AttributeTypes } from 'vtk.js/Sources/Common/DataModel/DataSetAttributes/Constants';
import { FieldDataTypes } from 'vtk.js/Sources/Common/DataModel/DataSet/Constants';

import controlPanel from './controller.html';

// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Standard rendering code setup
// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------

const fullScreenRenderer = vtkFullScreenRenderWindow.newInstance({
  background: [0, 0, 0],
});
const renderer = fullScreenRenderer.getRenderer();
const renderWindow = fullScreenRenderer.getRenderWindow();

// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Example code
// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// create a filter on the fly, sort of cool, this is a random scalars
// filter we create inline, for a simple cone you would not need
// this
// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------

const coneSource = vtkConeSource.newInstance({ height: 100.0, radius: 50.0 });
// const coneSource = vtkConeSource.newInstance({ height: 1.0, radius: 0.5 });
const filter = vtkCalculator.newInstance();

filter.setInputConnection(coneSource.getOutputPort());
// filter.setFormulaSimple(FieldDataTypes.CELL, [], 'random', () => Math.random());
filter.setFormula({
  getArrays: (inputDataSets) => ({
    input: [],
    output: [
      {
        location: FieldDataTypes.CELL,
        name: 'Random',
        dataType: 'Float32Array',
        attribute: AttributeTypes.SCALARS,
      },
    ],
  }),
  evaluate: (arraysIn, arraysOut) => {
    const [scalars] = arraysOut.map((d) => d.getData());
    for (let i = 0; i < scalars.length; i++) {
      scalars[i] = Math.random();
    }
  },
});

const mapper = vtkMapper.newInstance();
mapper.setInputConnection(filter.getOutputPort());

const actor = vtkActor.newInstance();
actor.setMapper(mapper);
actor.setPosition(20.0, 0.0, 0.0);

renderer.addActor(actor);
renderer.resetCamera();
renderWindow.render();

// -----------------------------------------------------------
// UI control handling
// -----------------------------------------------------------

fullScreenRenderer.addController(controlPanel);
const representationSelector = document.querySelector('.representations');
const resolutionChange = document.querySelector('.resolution');
const vrbutton = document.querySelector('.vrbutton');

representationSelector.addEventListener('change', (e) => {
  const newRepValue = Number(e.target.value);
  actor.getProperty().setRepresentation(newRepValue);
  renderWindow.render();
});

resolutionChange.addEventListener('input', (e) => {
  const resolution = Number(e.target.value);
  coneSource.setResolution(resolution);
  renderWindow.render();
});

vrbutton.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  if (vrbutton.textContent === 'Send To VR') {
    fullScreenRenderer.getOpenGLRenderWindow().startVR();
    vrbutton.textContent = 'Return From VR';
  } else {
    fullScreenRenderer.getOpenGLRenderWindow().stopVR();
    vrbutton.textContent = 'Send To VR';
  }
});

// -----------------------------------------------------------
// Make some variables global so that you can inspect and
// modify objects in your browser's developer console:
// -----------------------------------------------------------

global.source = coneSource;
global.mapper = mapper;
global.actor = actor;
global.renderer = renderer;
global.renderWindow = renderWindow;
```

Note: Tested on Latest Version of Chrome & Firefox (64 bit). Controller Type is HTC Vive.

**Update 1:**
We found this option not development, so that I share updated link now [Github Link](https://github.com/Kitware/vtk-js/issues/1002)